# Azure Indoor Maps show Unit alternative Name (nameAlt)

Tags: azure, azure-maps

I would like to ask if there is a way on how to display the nameAlt of a unit instead of the unit label in displaying the indoor map.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/drawing-package-guide
In the drawing package guide, it shows the unit label but how can we also display the nameAlt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not found any documentation about it. However, I have found that Azure Indoor Maps is using [Mapbox GL JS](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/guides/) as a rendering engine. For this reason, it seems that some documentation of Mapbox GL JS can be helpful until Azure Indoor Maps have more documentation. https://www.mapbox.com/blog/azure-maps-adds-data-driven-styling-powered-by-mapbox-gl

In this case, we have used the setLayoutProperty (https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/map/#map#setlayoutproperty and https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/language-switch/) method to change it. However, we are not sure if the property name will change in the future, Azure Indoor Maps is on preview, and this kind of change can be risky.

This is the code snippet that we have used in our project to display the nameAlt property.

```
map.events.add('render', function (e) {
            //Used the render function to get all the layers, including the layers for indoor maps.
            //Set the nameAlt in the text-field instead of name in indoor_global_unit_label
            map.map.setLayoutProperty('microsoft.maps.indoor.labels_indoor.indoor_global_unit_label', 'text-field', '{nameAlt}');
        });
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

The display name is handled by the SDK and currently there is no way to override that.